# How to connect amp pages in my node js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to connect my amp form to my node.js code. I have written other parts of code but unable to figure out how to connect amp page to my nods.js code.

Please go through my code and please comment your code with amp pages connection with nodsjs script.

Answer (score 0):

```
##this is my code, Facing problem to connect amp with nods js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 2190;
 const path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ' '));

var names;
var mobiles;
var email_ids;
const Airtable = require('airtable');

Airtable.configure({
    endpointUrl: 'https://api.airtable.com',
    apiKey: 'keyhpWH3acCslB9r6'
});

const base = Airtable.base("appDLlpi8sMoel1Co");
const base_name  = base("Applicants");

app.get('/api/users', function(req,res) {
    //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/def.html');
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
});

app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {

    names = req.body.name;
    mobiles = req.body.mobile;
    email_ids = req.body.email_id;

//    res.send(names + ' ' + mobiles + ' ' + email_ids);

        console.log(names);
        console.log(mobiles);
        console.log(email_ids)

        base_name.create({

            "Name": names,
            "Mobile": mobiles,
            "email-id": email_ids

        }, function (err, record) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(record.getId());
        });

    res.status(200).json({message : 'Thanks for reachinf out. We would get back to you soon'});
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```